# Display posts I console windows, and capture the same message in another program

Tags: c#

I'm trying to capture the information output of a process (Case 1) in another program (Case 2).

My current code is:

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.FileName = caminhoExecutavel;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
si.CreateNoWindow = false;

//executo o processo
processo = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(si);

// Configurações do processo.
processo.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(processo_OutputDataReceived);
processo.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
processo.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

I want to show the console messages as it normally would, **and** capture these same messages in another application.  Currently I can only allow the output to be shown normally **or** redirect it and access it in my other application.